# regular value of homotopy F is regular value for F_t

Tags: differential-topology

Let $M,N$ be smooth manifolds of the same dimension, let $I=[0,1]$ and say we have a smooth map $F:M \times I \to N$ with regular value $y \in N$. Is $y$ then also a regular value of $F_t := F(\cdot,t)$ for all $t \in I$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider $M = N = S^1$, parameterized by an angle $\theta$. Define

$$
F(\theta, t) = t
$$
Then the derivative of $F$ at $(\theta, t)$ is
$$
\pmatrix{0\\1}
$$
which is maximal rank, hence $F$ is regular at $(\theta, t)$.

On the other hand, $F_0(\theta, t) = 0$ for all $\theta$, hence its derivative is the $0$-matrix, which does not have maximal rank.

Comment: I guess you meant to say $N=R$? Anyway I see the point. Thanks!

Comment: No, I meant $N = S^1$. Basically, at time $t$ the entire circle $M$ is sent to the single point of $N$ at angle $t$. But you could also use $N = \Bbb R$ and it works equally well.